Why writing CTRL+C to child process stdin does not terminate process in Node.js while piping it does?
I have a function that I use for testing a command line application. It uses Node.js child_process.exec to run shell commands, like this:
const proc = child_process.exec(command, { env, timeout }, (error) =>
  errorHandler(error)
);

I then listen to events from proc.stdout and respond to prompts by writing to proc.stdin. I would like to pass SIGINT signal to the child process by writing ASCII characters representing CTRL + C to gracefully stop the process. I have tried '^C' and '\x03' but they don't work. However, piping these characters to the command works:
child_process.exec(`printf '^C' | command`);

What is the difference between these two approaches? Why writing to stdin doesn't work while piping does?
Note! I'm using the default /bin/sh in Ubuntu (dash). Neither approach works on Windows.

I suspect it has something to do with stdin being a file descriptor versus output of printf being interpreted by the shell (sh) first and then sending the signal.
But you should probably use https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#subprocesskillsignal

There’s no way printf '^C' | command is right – that just prints the characters ^ and C (which is not how Ctrl+C works) to a new instance of the command. If it appears to work, it’s for some other reason; it doesn’t send SIGINT.

Here is the problem, the text ^C doesn't terminate anything, it's in fact meaningless.
What kills a process is sending the SIGINT signal. Now in a terminal CTRL+C or ^C is a shortcut for sending the SIGINT signal, however, what you are doing is just sending a text.
If you want to kill the process properly you must send the SIGINT signal. You can do that using this code child_process.kill('SIGINT');
